# Min & Max value for colorbar doesn't match DensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color, legending

```
font=18;

DensityPlot[LogTQ+LogA,{LogTQ,-2,1},{LogA,2,6},
 PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic,
  LegendLabel->StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],Subscript[P,C]]],
 FrameTicksStyle->Directive[font],
 FrameLabel->(StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],#]&/@{Subscript[T,Q],A}),
 LabelStyle->Directive[font],PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->"SunsetColors"]
```

It produces:

[image]

Now let's say that I am only interested on P_C when it is bigger than 4. All things below 4 should be dark purple and the colored only be used for 4 and higher values. I thought that doing the following would do the correct output.

```
DensityPlot[LogTQ+LogA,{LogTQ,-2,1},{LogA,2,6},
 PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"SunsetColors",{2,4}},
  LegendLabel->StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],Subscript[P,C]]],
 FrameTicksStyle->Directive[font],
 FrameLabel->(StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],#]&/@{Subscript[T,Q],A}),
 LabelStyle->Directive[font],PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->"SunsetColors"]
```

Unfortunately it doesnt:

[image]

The colors used on the plot are basically totally uncorrelated from the color bar. How can I fix it ?

[edit] I did what is proposed in the comment but it doesn't fix the issue:

```
DensityPlot[LogTQ+LogA,{LogTQ,-2,1},{LogA,2,6},
 PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"SunsetColors",{2,4}},
  LegendLabel->StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],Subscript[P,C]]],
 FrameTicksStyle->Directive[font],
 FrameLabel->(StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],#]&/@{Subscript[T,Q],A}),
 LabelStyle->Directive[font],
 PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",ColorFunctionScaling->False]
```

[image]

**Also, please I would like to have explanations about the command. I looked at the documentation of the ColorScaling but it is not really helpfull**.

[edit2]: I tried the workaround proposed by @Ulrich Neumann. But with a slightly different function I have a weird behavior.

My code:

```
minColor=4*10^6;
maxColor=10^7;
ff[logTQ_,logA_]:=Max[Min[maxColor,10^(LogTQ)*10^(LogA)],minColor]
DensityPlot[ff[logTQ,logA],{LogTQ,-2,1},{LogA,2,6},
 PlotLegends->BarLegend[{"SunsetColors",{minColor,maxColor}},
  LegendLabel-> "Test"],
 FrameLabel->{StringForm["``(``)",Subscript[log,10],Subscript[T,Q]],
              StringForm["``(A)",Subscript[log,10]]} ,
 PlotRange->All,ColorFunction->"SunsetColors"]
```

The plot:

[image]

Why is it doing this weird white line ? And how to correct it ?

**Also, I would like the simplest possible solution to my problem. I think that what I want to plot is extremly standard and is typically done with a single option in many many languages. I would like to avoid to write a bunch of code for such simple ask for a plot. An adaptative solution (i.e if the colorfunction is changed the behavior keeps being correct) would also be nice.**

Comment: Add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann look at my edit. It doesnt fix it. Thanks !

Comment: @StarBucK You can e.g. use: "ColorFunction -> (Hue[Max[#, .5]] &)", but take care. The argument is scaled form 0..1. Further, you need to adapt the color of the Legend by hand. If you specify "BarLegend[{"SunsetColors"..." it will always show {SunsetColors". But the numbers are correct.

Comment: "Why is it doing this weird white line ? And how to correct it ?" `Exclusions -> None`, notice @UlrichNeumann has already set this in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**  If you are willing to use the ***first color***  in the built-in color scheme (which is `Black` for  `"SunsetColors"`, not `Purple`) for all function values below 2 and the ***last color*** (`White` for `"SunsetColors"`) for all values above 4 (so that you will not need the extra work to construct a custom color function), then

simply use [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) on the first argument  in `DensityPlot` to clip the function values (and add the option `Exclusions -> None` to remove the *"weird white line"*):

```
DensityPlot[Clip[x + y, {2, 4}], {x, -2, 1}, {y, 2, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotPoints -> 300
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

***Further examples:***

```
ClearAll[f, cf, x, y]
Grid[#, Dividers -> {None, All}, Spacings -> {2, 2}] &@
 Transpose @
  Table[DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 1}, {y, 2, 6}, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    PlotLabel -> Column[{cf, f[x, y]}, Alignment -> Center], 
    ColorFunction -> cf, PlotPoints -> 200, Exclusions -> None, 
    ImageSize -> 300], 
  {f, {# + #2 &, Clip[# + #2, {2, 4}] &}}, 
  {cf, { Hue, GrayLevel, "Rainbow", "TemperatureMap", "SolarColors"}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

To  make ***"all values higher than 4  all white and all values below 2 all purple"***, we can modify the color function `"SunsetColors"` as follows:

```
blendcolors = DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument["SunsetColors"]
```

[image]

Remove the first color to make the colors start from purple:

```
bl = Rest @ blendcolors ;
```

Use `bl` to define a new color function (i) using [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) to map all values below 2 to 2 and all values above 4 to 4, and (ii) [`Rescale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rescale.html)ing the resulting values to the unit interval:

```
cF = Blend[bl, Rescale[Clip[#, {2, 4}], {2, 4}]] &;
```

(1) Use `cF` as the option value for `ColorFunction` , (2) add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, and (3) use `{cF, {2, 4}}` as the first argument of `BarLegend`:

```
DensityPlot[LogTQ + LogA, {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{cF, {2, 4}}, 
   LegendLabel -> StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font], 
 FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}), 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[font], 
 ColorFunction -> cF, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it looks extremely complicated for something very simply done in many languages. Isn't there a simpler option to put to ask for this ? I also saw the next answer (it works in the simple example but I have a weird stuff occuring for my "real" plot that I need to understand with that solution)

Comment: @StarBucK, what makes it _complicated_ is the modification to the built-in color function "SunsetColors" needed to meet  the requirement _"all values below 2 all purple"_. If it is ok to use  _"all values below 2 all **black**"_, then you can simply use `Clip[LogTQ + LogA, {2, 4}]` as the first argument in `DensityPlot` (i.e. `DensityPlot[Clip[LogTQ + LogA, {2, 4}], {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotPoints -> 300, Exclusions -> None]`).

Comment: Thx for your comment. My point is that I would like something robust (if I change the colorfunction it should adapt), and that corresponds to typical way of presenting plots. It is very frequent to associate the highest color of the plot to values that saturate the upper value. And the lowest color to value that "under-saturate" the lower value. I am actually extremly surprized that this is not already implemented in mathematica. If it is really not possible to have a solution according to it I guess I will use a complicated code to do it but I would **really** like to avoid it.

Comment: @StarBucK "And the lowest color to value that 'under-saturate' the lower value." As mentioned by kglr in his last comment, purple is not the _lowest color_ of `"SunsetColors"`, the lowest color in this case is `Black`.

Answer (score 4):

Add `RegionFunction`

```
DensityPlot[LogTQ + LogA, {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
  LegendLabel -> StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font],
 FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}),
 LabelStyle -> Directive[font], PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction ->  "SunsetColors" ,
 RegionFunction -> (2 < #3 < 4 &)]
```

[image]

**workaround python**

restrict the density function

```
DensityPlot[
 Max[Min[4, LogTQ + LogA], 2], {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6}, 
 PlotLegends ->BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {2, 4}},
  LegendLabel -> StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]],
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font],
 FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}),
 LabelStyle -> Directive[font], PlotRange -> All,
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your answer but this is not exactly what I want to do. What I want to do is to have a color range between 2 and 4 such that all values higher than 4 basically "saturates" and are all white. All values below 2 also saturates and are all purple. I would like a simple way to implement it (in python it is automatically done as soon as you restrict the range of the color for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your edit. It indeed works with your function (and your solution is "quite" simple so I like it). However with a slightly different function I have a weird behavior that I do not understand. Look at my edit. How to fix it ? Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Overlay two plots and you get something like

```
Show[DensityPlot[4, {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6},ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"],DensityPlot[LogTQ + LogA, {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6},PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic], PlotRange -> {4, 7},ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the connection between the range used in `BarLegend` and the data range in the `DensityPlot` is not intuitive. I think the problem here, though, is the default range used by the `ColorFunction`, which is [0, 1].

I think a relatively simple way to tie together the `BarLegend` range and the `ColorFunction` range is to use a variable that can be applied to `BarLegend` as-is and rescaled to [0, 1] for use in whatever `ColorFunction` you'd like. Here, I used the variable `colorRange` to accomplish this conversion.

Setting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` is required for my solution, as it passes the unscaled data values to `ColorFunction`, where the `Rescale` function maps them into the correct [0, 1] range for display by `ColorFunction`. (I also added the `PlotPoints` option to improve the color densities for a smoother appearance.)

```
colorRange = {2, 4};
DensityPlot[LogTQ + LogA, {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA, 2, 6}
    , PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Automatic, colorRange}
        , LegendLabel -> StringForm["``(``)"
            , Subscript[log, 10]
            , Subscript[P, C]
        ]
    ]
    , FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font]
    , FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A})
    , LabelStyle -> Directive[font]
    , PlotRange -> All
    , ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SunsetColors"][Rescale[#, colorRange, {0, 1}]] &)
    , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
    , PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image: DensityPlot]

Answer (score 0):

I agree the answers are not somehow dissatisfactory but really.

I read about DensityPlot a lot and found that Mathematica derives it internally from ContourPlot in an object-oriented manner as a built-in with different a set of options. It is in some circumstances slower than `ContourPlot` but not in all.

So I answer with this solution:

```
cp0 = ContourPlot[
  If[LogTQ + LogA <= 4, LogTQ + LogA, Nothing], {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA,
    2, 6}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Contours -> 99, 
  ContourLabels -> True, ContourStyle -> None, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {2, 4}}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font], 
  FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", 
       Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}), 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[font], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: ContourPlot as built-in from which DensityPlot is derived]

The remaining problem is still evident. The contour line on the linear surface foes from the upper leftmost corner to the point `(1.0,3.0)`. For the default setting of `ContourPlot` this is used and can be seen brilliant. The border between this contour line and the first color visible is really big for a linear surface.

The more contour lines the better the resolution and the smaller the white stripe.

This can be worse as this for a small number of contour lines:

```
cp0 = ContourPlot[
  If[LogTQ + LogA <= 4, LogTQ + LogA, Nothing], {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA,
    2, 6}, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Contours -> 3, 
  ContourLabels -> True, ContourStyle -> None, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{"SunsetColors", {2, 4}}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font], 
  FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", 
       Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}), 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[font], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: really large white contour stripe between contour line 4 and 3 for Contour->3]

In comparison to DensityPlot and the Clip and the rest of all of it, this reflects the linearity of the function in the question at the highest degree. It allows to let the white strip below the contour line to vanish if the upper limit is adopted appropriately corresponding to the step size of the contour set chosen.

Define another sunshine colorfunction:

[image: Colorfunction Sunshine without Black and White]

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[
  If[LogTQ + LogA <= 4, LogTQ + LogA, Nothing], {LogTQ, -2, 1}, {LogA,
    2, 6}, ColorFunction -> cF1, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  Contours -> 101, ContourLabels -> True, ContourStyle -> None, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[{cF1, {0, 4}}, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     StringForm["``(``)", Subscript[log, 10], Subscript[P, C]]], 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[font], 
  FrameLabel -> (StringForm["``(``)", 
       Subscript[log, 10], #] & /@ {Subscript[T, Q], A}), 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[font], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Better and robust DensityPlot replacement with a linear color scale]

Other have similar problems:

[barlegend-does-not-illustrate-my-colorfunction-correctly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149660/barlegend-does-not-illustrate-my-colorfunction-correctly)

[control-the-number-of-decimal-digits-in-custom-ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163276/control-the-number-of-decimal-digits-in-custom-ticks/163298#163298)

and some more in this community.

For further knowledge what is possible look at

[method options for DensitPlot and ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69448/method-options-for-densityplot-and-contourplot/69486#69486).